# How can I mitigate scam comments on my YouTube videos?

Tags: spam, scam

I'm an author of software aid for online game League of Legends. I have posted several (precisely four) videos that explain how the software works and is meant to be used.

The game involves paid content to some degree which results in occurrence of scammers. The most typical scam is the promise of acquiring free paid content, while in fact paid content is typically stolen from scammed user in effect.

I get about eight comments promoting a scam in a week, usually from French users (actually they are quite obviously bots). YouTube successfully marks more than 75% of those comments as possible spam, however this still requires me to delete them. And about quarter of the comments is right away visible.

I need a way to mitigate those comments because they are obvious attempt to harm people. But I would rather not invest much time in it.

How can I protect YouTube content from harmful links without much effort?

Comment: Hold for moderation: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/111870?hl=en

Comment: Add a blacklist: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6109622

Comment: I didn't want to hold comments for moderation because it would call my honesty as a software author in question.

Comment: This is off-topic here and a question for YouTube support.

Comment: Could you extend on how it's off topic please? I've seen lot of questions here that can be answered by Google support. For example this one: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/97064/20361

Comment: That question is about the architecture. You are asking about the *use* of a particular application. The answer to which is *actually* in a support page. This isn't a general question about comment spam, but specifically about YouTube. Also, I Googled "YouTube comment spam" and that's how I found the links I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to schroeder's comments leading to google Help center, I decided to set up a blacklist of words typical for scam. Comments containing those words will require approval.

The blacklist can be set there: https://www.youtube.com/comment_management

It's a comma separated list of words or phrases:

[image: image description]

You still will have the option to show the comment if it's a valid comment and not a spam.